# How To Change The Row Height Based On Cell Value In Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a monitoring database that automates status in one column based on the latest input. Now, when the word "final" appear in the status cell, I manually adjust the row height to 15. Is it possible to set this automatically that when the word "final" appear in any cell of a column, the row height will adjust to 15 only?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only trigger that ever come close to that are onEdit and onChange and they don't respond to no user edits.  So the only thing that remains are timebased triggers which would allow to poll which would require you to reread the data and compare it to what you already have and detect changes that way.

I seriously doubt that Google will ever unleash that kind of trigger power.  They have too many users and I suspect triggers like that could bring their server to their knees pretty quickly.  Especially with users working together with that specific goal in mind.

Comment: Thank you. I believe this can be done only through an excel macro thus I thought it may be possible as well with gsheet. for now I'll continue the manual adjustment. thanks again.

Comment: You could possibly be more efficient by using the control key to select a bunch of rows and have a script go through an set the row heights on all selected rows.  That may make the work less tedious.

Comment: yes sir that's exactly what Im doing for now.  thank you.